# How do scientists determine the height measurement of a tsunami wave after the event?

Tags: tsunami

How is information concerning the height of a tsunami obtained?
Does not the incoming and out going wave scour the area of natural and man made structures, hindering an accurate measurement?

Comment: if you google"how is tsunami measured"you get 19million hits.